# Any callback methods to let my fragment know it's RecyclerView.Adapter added/removed items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment containing a RecyclerView + LinearLayoutManager + RecyclerView.Adapter. I want to let my fragment know when items are added/removed from my dataset. Is there a nice way to do that or do I have to use Callback interfaces or EventBus?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `registerAdapterDataObserver`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#registerAdapterDataObserver(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver)

FYI, this gets notified when adapter contents change. That does not necessarily mean that they'll become visible. (depends on your adapter size and scroll position of the Layout).

Also, any change applied to the adapter gets handled (e.g. converted to views) in the next layout pass.